# How to insert space between a number and a character /string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to insert space between a number and string / character

I have a regex question.

How do I insert a space between a numeric character and a letter.

For example:

```
var sentence = "It contains 37mg of salt"
```

I want the output to be:

```
It contains 37 mg of salt.
```

Answer (score 4):

Match a number, lookahead for a letter, then replace with the number with a space after it:

```js
var sentence = "It contains 37mg of salt";
const result = sentence.replace(/\d(?=[a-z])/i, '$& ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match the number using `(\d+)` and add a white space in the replaced string in front of the matched number

```js
var sentence = "It contains 37mg of salt"
let res = sentence.replace(/(\d+)/g,"$1 ")
console.log(res)
```